# I get an Access Denied error when calling LsaQueryInformationPolicy(), and I'm an admin

Tags: c#, windows, unmanaged, local-security-authority

I get this error return whether I try [`LsaQueryInformationPolicy()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa378313%28VS.85%29.aspx) on the local host or on some other machine in the domain. The flags I use for [`LsaOpenPolicy()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa378299(v=VS.85).aspx) are `POLICY_LOOKUP_NAMES | POLICY_VIEW_LOCAL_INFORMATION` but I also tried `POLICY_LOOKUP_NAMES | POLICY_VIEW_LOCAL_INFORMATION | READ_CONTROL` without success.

The user I'm logged in as is a local admin both on my machine and on all others I'm trying this.

For the second parameter to `LsaQueryInformationPolicy()` I use `PolicyAuditEventsInformation`.

I'm able to use [`LsaEnumerateAccountRights()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms721790%28VS.85%29.aspx) against the same host, using the same policy handle, successfully.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use `POLICY_LOOKUP_NAMES | GENERIC_READ | POLICY_VIEW_LOCAL_INFORMATION` instead of `POLICY_LOOKUP_NAMES | POLICY_VIEW_LOCAL_INFORMATION`. It works on my computer.

**UPDATED**: To be more exactly you need only `POLICY_VIEW_AUDIT_INFORMATION` during opening of `LsaOpenPolicy()` to read audit information.